# solr increase score for some specially documents

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I want to increase score for the docs when their type(one field in schema.xml) is equal to "xxx"(string value).

means they can be easier to be searched

May be I can use "bf" parameter, But I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bq`, which allows you to boost documents that match a given query.

```
bq=field:xxx^5
```

The value `5` can be changed depending on how much you want your boost to affect the score.